# Proguard issue with Support Library and RecyclerView onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, proguard, android-support-library, android-proguard

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   my.packa.CustomAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   my.package.name.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(Unknown
>   Source) at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(Unknown Source)
>   at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(Unknown Source) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(Unknown
>   Source) at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055) at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) at
>   android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(Unknown Source)
>   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14948) at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631) at
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(Unknown Source) at

ProGuard Rules look like this:

```
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keep class java.lang.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.**
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.design.widget.** { *; }
-keep class my.package.name.CustomAdapter


# Hide warnings about references to newer platforms in the library
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
# don't process support library
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }


-dontwarn android.support.design.**
-keep class android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.design.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.design.R$* { *; }
```

The issue happens only in release apk when proguard is running

Comment: share please what is in onCreateViewHolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following rules to your proguard file:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature

#-keep class au.com.flightcentre.fragment.** { *; }

# Preserve the special static methods that are required in all enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Serializable {
  public static final android.os.Serializable$Creator *;
}
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```

I don't think it's necessary to keep your custom adapter, but you do have to keep model classes (your java objects). Something like this:

```
-keep class com.nnacres.app.model.** { *; }
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: you were right, all i needed was to add the model class for the RecyclerView in the proguard rules file.  I used keepclassmembers rule.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following rules should work in your case.

```
-dontwarn com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.VideoDecoder
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class java.lang.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.support.v7.**

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Just keep all the class names intact under `com.google`, `com.android`, `android.support.v7`. Remove the keep interface as well.

I do not think you need to add the following in your `proguard-rules.pro`. So you might consider omitting it.

```
-keep class my.package.name.CustomAdapter
```

Here is a working `progurad-rules.pro` file from my project.

```
-adaptclassstrings
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-allowaccessmodification
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.github.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class com.android.** { *; }
-keep class junit.** { *; }
-keep class org.mockito.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn org.junit.**
-dontwarn org.mockito.**

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
    public static *** i(...);
    public static *** e(...);
}

-printmapping build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt
```